# Eject USB storage on Windows 8.1: 2 different brand drives appear as sub-options under same option

Tags: windows-8.1, usb-storage, safely-remove-hardware

I have a HGST Touro 500Gb USB3 drive and a Samsung 1Tb USB3 drive attached to my Windows 8.1 Pro machine and a few other drives as well.

When I go to safely disconnect one of these drives, in the menu list of drives to disconnect, the Touro and Samsung always appear as greyed out sub options under a selectable main option. All other drives listed each have their own main selectable option and a greyed out sub option.

So for either the Samsung or the Touro, I cannot choose individually which one to disconnect, if I select the option, one of them disconnects and then I have to select it again to disconnect the other.

**Update**

Screenshot to follow once I get home from work, but here is a text-based illustration of how it looks:

1) Right click on USB list in bottom right hand of task bar
2) Menu pops up, options

- **Samsung S2** (selectable option)

  - Samsung S2
  - Touro
- **Other Drive** (selectable option)

**Update 2**

Screenshot, as promised, showing the 2 drives appearing under one heading:

[image]

Comment: @RowlandShaw - added a screenshot - I agree that this helps explain my question.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that, depending on what you're using the sticks for, you don't need to 'safely remove' them (i.e., you can just unplug them)? Then again, with such large capacities, you're probably not using them for simple file storage?

Comment: No, drives should always be safely removed. I am writing to them and reading from them. Given that I am writing to them, they do need to be safely removed to allow Window to flush any buffers and close any open files etc., to prevent corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your hotplug dialog to show all options, rather than just devices plugged in.  This is something like 'show all drivers'.

It wull show a tree, and you can unmount either drive without unloading the base Samsung S2 driver.

Comment: OK thanks Wendy, I'll check it out when I get home from work either tonight or tomorrow. My guess is that a device inquiry command sent to each drive returns something similar enough that the code in Windows 8.1 Pro doesn't handle well enough to distinguish properly between the 2. Curiously, this problem doesn't happen in Windows 7.

Comment: This might help unmount the specific drive but it still leaves me wondering why they appear under the same 'base' heading.

Comment: You could search on the internet for `unknowndevices` by `halfdone software`.  It's free, and basically looks along the PNP bus.  It should detect that the controllers on the two hard drives are made by the same company, and use the same PNP ID.

Comment: +1 Good tip Wendy, but why does this only happen on Windows 8 and not when I do it in Windows 7?

Comment: I really don't know.  I use Windows 2000, mainly.  Some of my laptops have a later OS on them, mainly Windows XP.  I am not sure about Windows NT 6.x (vista, seven and eight).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you could try is to go to Control Panel, then click Devices and Printers, look for the offending device and select that icon. Right click on the icon and select "Remove Device." After the offending device has been removed insert the drive you want to be used and then the other. This problem occurs with drives that are part of the HGST family of hard drives (G-Tech, Touro, etc.) Which are all owned by Western Digital, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can just open windows explorer, right-click the drive in question and eject or disconnect it from there.
You could even make shortcuts on your desktop to the drives to facilitate this.